# XSLT to transform XML: selecting uuids and sorting in order

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, uuid

```
   ##
```

---

### I do have the large xml file with multiple uuids grouped under different elements. I want them to be sorted in each group. can someone please post they ideas on this.----------

Here is the xslt file using to format

Expected Output: To Sort all uids in the file

Comment: XSLT and XPath have sorting functions. Where are you stuck? At least provide a well-formed XML input and post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is xslt file which im using, I need to know datatype needs to be given to sort uuids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort the `uuid` elements, then you must apply the sort instruction to them, from the context of their parent `uuids`  element - not to non-existing `test` elements from the context of a non-existing `table` element.

Also, UUIDs are not numbers and it makes no sense to sort them as numbers. In fact, it's not clear what sense it makes to sort them at all, since they are by definition meaningless. Still, if you want, you could do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uuids">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="uuid">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQP

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. can I also know how can we sort this.... <history>         <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3b5-23f2-8000-9ba7-011c48011c48_237484"/>         <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3e5-e568-8000-9ba9-011c48011c48_243829"/>         <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3e5-e568-8000-9ba9-011c48011c48_250806"/>         <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3e5-e568-8000-9ba9-011c48011c48_252670"/>     </history>

Comment: Make your template match `history`. The use `<xsl:apply-templates select="historyInfo">` and `<xsl:sort select="@versionUuid"/>`.

Comment: P.S. Please do not post code in comments. Either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried with the above changes. but it isnt working. I just updated question. can you please take a look at the code?

Comment: Please edit you question again and show (1) a **well-formed** XML input, (2) your current XSLT attempt  and (3) the expected output. --- Also, the changes you made make no sense. I suggest you spend an hour with an XPath/XSLT tutorial before posting here. Otherwise you won't be able to understand the answers given to you and apply them.

Comment: Sure, I'll take a deep loop into that. Can you please check the xslt file and output now?

Comment: Your XML is NOT well-formed: it lacks a single root element. And there is no expected output (as code). See if this helps: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQP/1

Comment: Hi micheal, thanks for the response. i have some progress on this issue and seeing few more issues now. can you please check this question and let me know your thoughts.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639594/issues-with-sorting-uuids-in-xml-with-xslt

Comment: I just closed it. can you check this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639594/issues-with-sorting-uuids-in-xml-with-xslt

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- If the uuid elements are not always in a uuids element, can replace with *[uuid] -->
    <xsl:template match="uuids">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="uuid">
                <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniTR

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. can I also know how can we sort this....                   `<history>
        <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3b5-23f2-8000-9ba7-011c48011c48_237484"/>
        <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3e5-e568-8000-9ba9-011c48011c48_243829"/>
        <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3e5-e568-8000-9ba9-011c48011c48_250806"/>
        <historyInfo versionUuid="_a-0000e3e5-e568-8000-9ba9-011c48011c48_252670"/>
    </history>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the .xslt tempalte which is working fine

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uuids">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="uuid">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="history">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="historyInfo">
            <xsl:sort select="@versionUuid"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```