# Issues with sorting uuids in xml with XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath, uuid

Here is the part of .xml file which I need to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. its removing the 'standalone="yes"?' part in the first line

Add `standalone="yes"` to the [`xsl:output`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#element-output)

> 2. its removing the value '[CDATA[' in element

Declare the namespace `http://www.test.com/ae/types/2009` and then use`cdata-section-elements="ae:value"` on the `xsl:output` element.

> 3. its combing the 'process_model_port' element in single line and adding the version at the end of it which i dont see in source file.

Are you referring to `schemaVersion="007.000.004"`? Because that is in the source XML. As for how the element is serialized, and whether it's one line or not, that shouldn't be a concern and I don't think you have a way to influence that in how it is serialized.

An example of declaring the namespace with the prefix `ae` and the adjustments to the `xsl:output` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ae="http://www.test.com/ae/types/2009">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ae:value" standalone="yes"/>
```

Comment: Hi Mads, thanks for the quick reponse. Point 3 makes sense. I'm didnt get point 1 & 2. when I added '@standalone="yes"' to .xslt file its throwing error saying that 'lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name, line 1, column 31'

Comment: and regarding point 2, can you please send the line how to add it? i didnt get how to declare the namespace in my xslt file

Comment: I had included `@` to indicate that it was an attribute. Sorry if that was confusing. I'll take that out, to be more clear of what literal text needs to be added to the `xsl:output` eleme.

Comment: Noprob, I can see the standalone=yes attribute now in the output file. But adding cdata-section-element throws the following error  'lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Attribute 'cdata-section-elements': The value '(null)' is not a valid QName.'

Comment: and you also added the namespace declaration on your xsl:stylesheet or xsl:output element? `xmlns:ae="http://www.test.com/ae/types/2009"`

Comment: Nope its not working, and now its throwing new issue. can you please check the new code box i added in the question? its adding Cdata to other values

Comment: The new source file is not valid (no declared namespace for the `a` or `xsi` namespace prefixes, and closing element for `<pvcs>`). Assuming that `a` is the `http://www.test.com/ae/types/2009` namespace, it's doing what I would expect, serializing the text() value as CDATA.

Comment: If you only want certain `value` elements serialized with CDATA, I'm not sure how to advise, other than not to worry about whether there is CDATA or not. Let the XML tools serialize for you and don't worry so much about what the text of the XML "looks like".

Comment: I just updated the boxes again, expected output is not to remove or add the new CDATA to the elements. just sort the uuid's.

Comment: If you want those other elements to be serialized with CDATA, then add the list of element names to the `cdata-section-elements="ae:value ae:stringId ae:timeZoneId"`.

Comment: Ya i dont see the CDATA removing now, but i only see its adding to the values which I shared in the box. here is what im using  ```<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ae:uuid ae:timeZoneId ae:stringId ae:name" standalone="yes"/>```

Comment: if I added ```ae:value``` its not removing the CDATA to values elements, but its adding it to new ones which arent in source