# xslt template to sort uuid's in xml with CDATA elements

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath, cdata

I have an xslt template which is used to sort the uuids in the same file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ae="http://www.test.com/ae/types/2009">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ae:uuid ae:timeZoneId ae:stringId ae:name" standalone="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uuids">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="uuid">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the xml file which I'm trying to parse, this is thelarge xml file, I'm copying the root of the xml files with the namespaces and the elements which are modified with CDATA.

Comment: You will need to show any relevant namespace declarations if you want help with specific code. An XML sample without namespace declarations but some XSLT code using prefixes as in `cdata-section-elements="ae:uuid ae:timeZoneId ae:stringId ae:name"` doesn't allow us to judge and fix the particular code. In general, XSLT can't preserve CDATA sections, its processing model works on a tree representation with text nodes that don't distinguish between text nodes and CDATA sections. For serialization of a result, you can, as you did, declare the CDATA section elements you need.

Comment: Your example XML doesn't show any namespaces applied to the content. Is this a snippet from a larger file? You need to ensure that namespaces are included, or your stylesheet won't work as expected when specifying the names of elements that you want serialized with CDATA. And this is basically the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/67639594/14419

Comment: thanks for your response. I just updated the question. can you guys please check it?

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes i opened the new one only for the specific issue. The previous question which you posted has multiple issues and i have few resolved.

Comment: Your edited input sample doesn't seem to have a CDATA section.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you check now?@MartinHonnen

Comment: So, which elements do you want to have CDATA in the output for the given input?

Comment: I dont want to change any element which has the Cdata, It should be like source only with the CDATA attribute. But its removing it if I didnt pass this  ```cdata-section-elements="ae:uuid ae:timeZoneId ae:stringId ae:name"``` in .xslt file. And new issue here is its also adding the CDATA to the new elements.

Comment: but the `uuid` element doesn't have CDATA in your input. Why are you adding it to your output? If you just want the `value` elements to have CDATA, then just use what I suggested in the previous question, which is also what Martin suggests in the answer to this question.

Comment: And I would advise not to be so concerned about CDATA. If you are using XML tools to read/write XML, it doesn't matter.

Comment: i want to copy the whole source xml to destination xml with the sorted uuids. So i dont want these Cdata to be deleted or to be inserted to any new elements

Comment: I get that you want to try to maintain fidelity and minimize change to the source file, but probably shouldn't be so concerned. If the data is serialized properly, it doesn't matter if CDATA is applied or not. When it gets read by XML tools, whether `<` happened to be an entity `&lt;` or numeric entity `&#60;` or the literal `<` character inside of CDATA blocks, it will be `<` when `text()` value is read (with XML tools). Typically when people care about CDATA they are doing something wrong, like substring of raw XML instead of using XML tools. The data is the same, it just looks different.

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen, thanks for the clarification. I understand that it doesnt change anything, but as I said my team is ONLY looking for changes in uuid's sorting. is there anyway we can avoid adding or removing the CDATA?

Answer (score 1):

`<xsl:template match="uuids">` doesn't make any sense if the input has no `uuids` elements.

As for the current sample `cdata-section-elements="ae:value"` would fix the `<value><![CDATA[AMNT Get test ]]></value>` elements but as you also have `a:value` where you have a different prefix but the same namespace I don't think the XSLT output attributes will allow you to distinguish them, if that is what you want.

Comment: I didnt include the uuids. because its  large file and also they're working as expected